# MYSQL CONCAT_WS and UNIX_TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp, concat-ws

Hello I have date and time table:

```
date               time 
09-03-2014  06:17:15
09-03-2014  06:23:06
09-03-2014  06:28:57
09-03-2014  06:40:39
```

I will make this:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',date,time) AS newtime FROM hive96
newtime
09-03-2014 06:17:15
09-03-2014 06:23:06
09-03-2014 06:28:57
09-03-2014 06:40:39
```

than later I type this code:

```
SELECT unix_timestamp('2008-06-19 16:25:15'); <==newtime
```

I want to collect two query. I want `newtime` put in unix timestamp query.

Thank you

Comment: It looks like you are  storing your `date` column as a `VARCHAR` instead of a proper `DATETIME` type. If you are in a position to correct this, you are advised to do so.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael Berkowski stated, it would be best to change the type of your date column from `varchar` to `date` and that of your time column to `time`. If you can't do it, you've got to convert your string to `datetime`. MySQL provides the function `STR_TO_DATE()` to do this:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP( 
    STR_TO_DATE( 
        CONCAT_WS(' ', date, time), 
        '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')
    )
);
```

check the manual: [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for the format string